# Connect IBM Cognos to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cognos

Currently i'm using IBM Cognos Express, database from SQL Server 2008.
But error has occured when i try to retrieving database from SQL Server to IBM Cognos.
How to connect IBM Cognos Express to SQL Server 2008?
Thanks.

Comment: To get help with your specific problem you will need to include more details. What is the error exactly? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

What version of Cognos Express (9.0, 9.5)? Here are some generic instructions in the meantime;

- Start SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Go to Client Protocols and enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes
- Go to Protocols for SQLEXPRESS and enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes
- Then double click TCP/IP to go into its properties, click IP addresses tab, scroll to bottom for IPAll group
- Make TCP dynamic ports setting to be blank
- Make TCP port to be 1433
- Restart SQLExpress service
- In Cognos configuration you can then select SQL Server and COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS for database settings